# IIS 8.5 - website Settings - Export all the settings to Compare

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have been working on an ASP.NET 4.0 website and IIS 8.5 is used to host the website.

My website works fine in DEV but it does not work as expected in QA. Some functions are not working as it works in DEV server.

I would like to compare the IIS settings between DEV and QA server to identify the mismatch.

Is there any option to export all the IIS settings to a file? This can be used as backup and also to compare the settings with other servers.

Please let me know how to export all the IIS settings of a website to a file.

Thanks
Ashok

Comment: _What's_ not working in the production environment?
You can use appcmd to create a back-up of the IIS configuration, see `appcmd backup /?` for its help information. But there is more to it than just IIS config, what about ASP.NET (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\AspNet.config`, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\AspNet.config`, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\web.config` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\web.config`). And comparing the output of `appcmd list site [site name]` may give you some insights as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. it s useful. Will try that.